# CoreData and NSManagedObject Context - private vs. main

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is there a difference between triggering a CoreData (CRUD) operation with a private context using `performBlock` and triggering such an operation using the main context in a dispatch_async background queue?

Is it simply the case that one should not use main context in a background thread?

Link to apple docs is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

Answer (score 6):

You should **never** use a main queue context in a background thread.  That violates the thread confinement rules.

A main queue context should only every be accessed from the main queue (UI queue/thread) or from a `performBlock`.  If you are needing to do a non-UI related task then you should create a private queue context and access it via a `performBlock`.

To confirm you have your Core Data threading correct you can turn on the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` runtime setting.

Comment: I get that. But, I tested the two options and they both seem to work. So my question is whether this is just luck that the forbidden approach works...

Comment: It is a threading violation which means it will work *most* of the time and then fail in production with a high risk of data corruption.  That is why the debug setting exists; because threading bugs do not present themselves consistently.